# Very old animated show taking place in the insect world

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, animation

When I was little, I had this one VHS with home-taped cartoons [but not by us] that I watched endlessly. One of the cartoons was unknown to me even then, but it was very characteristic and I'd love to find it somewhere.

Here's what I know:

### Info about the cartoon

- Very old: I watched the tape about 20 years ago, but the other       cartoons on there were from the 60's and 70's, I think.
- It was hand-drawn, with very peculiar, sketch-like foregrounds (I remember those being present a lot).
- It was probably Eastern-European (perhaps Polish), considering the other cartoons on the tape ('[Nu, Pogodi!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu,_pogodi!)', '[Bolek and Lolek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolek_and_Lolek)', '[Reksio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reksio)'), but I think there was no dialog.
- In the context of those other shows, I assume it was also a show, but it might have been a short film.

### Details from the cartoon

The whole story took place at the scale of insects, but I'm not sure if *all* the characters were insects. 
At the beginning, we see a pirate - who was a moth or a beetle - on a boat. He drinks a bottle of wine and uses the empty bottle as a telescope to spot some sort of princess.
At some later point, the main character sword-fights this pirate, and I remember some appendages (e.g. antennae) being cut off of the pirate, like the [close-call haircut](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CloseCallHaircut).

The main character probably rode a grasshopper, or something similar.

I also remember a scene where the hero is in some odd building, and a villain keeps pulling levers and drawcords to spring all kinds of booby-traps on the hero. Remainders of previous heroes are scattered throughout the building (a bit like in the volcano in Shrek).
This scene may have been a different episode, if it was indeed a TV show, or just a continuation of the first part.

I really hope this rings a bell with someone, as google is not my friend on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be a polish animated series **Przygody Błękitnego Rycerzyka** from 1963 (can be translated "Adventures of Little Blue Knight"). Can't find anything about it in English, only polish sites come up.

It's a 13 episodes long short animation about a little knight rescuing princesses and is set in "bugs world"

Here are some pictures from it
[image]
[image]

and here's the episode with the pirate you described (the title is in Spanish/Italian? but that's the show)

Comment: That's the one! Oh, what marvellous memories came back :')